# Discord.js bot's presence isn't working fine

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I want to maky my presence show the numbers of orders from a json file into the bot's presence but it doesn't show anything and doesn't tell any errors in the console

```js
const fsn = require("fs-nextra");
module.exports = {
    name: 'ready',
    once: true,
    execute(client) {
      fsn.readJSON("./orders.json").then((orderDB) => {
            let amount = 0;
            for (let x in orderDB) {
              amount++;
               client.user.setPresence({
        status: 'online',
        activity: {
            name: `${amount} orders | .help`,
            type: "WATCHING"
        }       
        })
             }
      });  
        console.log(`Ready! Logged in as ${client.user.tag}`);
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to set a "}" after the loop. I changed you the mistake in the following code:

```js
const fsn = require("fs-nextra");
module.exports = {
    name: 'ready',
    once: true,
    execute(client) {
        fsn.readJSON("./orders.json").then((orderDB) => {
            let amount = 0;
            for (let x in orderDB) {
                amount++;
            }
            client.user.setPresence({
                status: 'online',
                activity: {
                    name: `${amount} orders | .help`,
                    type: "WATCHING"
                }
            })
        });
        console.log(`Ready! Logged in as ${client.user.tag}`);
    },
};
```

Comment: oh thanks, i have a quick question will this update every time there is a new order in the json file?

Comment: No because you just trigger this event on the ready event of the bot. So everytime the bot restarts and the ready event gets called their presence status is updated